# Grid on @UIScope annotated view strange behavior

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Vaadin 19.0.6, spring boot. Open the same view annotated with @UIScope in two different browsers or tabs, for example. Then request data for the grid in window1. Now navigate from the view in window1 and request different data for the grid in window2. Return back to view in window1 and you will see the same data in the grid as you have in window2. I don't understand yet how this could happen if you have @UIScope - the scope limited to browser tab. Some kind of DataProvider sharing?

Comment: UiScope is only a "browser" tab ( you have one UI per tab if you don't refresh the page). Maybe you are using a singleton Spring Bean ( @Component without scope annotation). If it's not the case, maybe you could post a sample of your code.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheGueriaud Service bean and DataProvider bean don't have Scope annotation neither Component annotation.  I've tried to mark Service and DataProvider with UiScope annotation without success. I've described situation and solution in my case in the answer down below.

Comment: Yes. As I said it's hard to guess without any code. In my opinion, you shouldn't have view or UI specific in your service layer because your service layer is (most of the time) shared as a Singleton. That's good that you found a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of this. It is easy to be confused which bean is "saved" in UiScope. For example, if you have DataProvider with Service bean then Service bean is not unique per view. You have to move all per view logic into DataProvider. This was my mistake.

PS. Some additional explanation. If you set some properties of Service bean from the View bean then these properties are set globally and when you return back to some view(doesn't matter where - tab, window, browser, session) which use the same service you will get the last global service state. I hope this will help someone.